# Ordering by Member of Composite Type Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

Take the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id serial primary key, txt text);
INSERT INTO test (id,txt) values (1,'one'),(2,'two'),(3,'three')
```

and custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE tttpe AS (id integer, name varchar(32), greee integer);
```

I am converting a query like this:

```
SELECT id, txt, (id+10) as gree FROM test ORDER BY 2
```

where the 2 is dynamic, to a query like this:

```
SELECT (id, txt, (id+10))::tttpe FROM test;  --order  by!?
```

but I want to order it by a member of the custom type, for example `txt.` How do I do this? Ideally I'd like to be able to use an integer index for the nth property but if that's not possible I can work around it.

UPDATE:

Based on Clodoaldo Neto
s answer I came up with the following:

```
SELECT (id,txt,g)::tttpe FROM (select id, txt, (id+10) FROM test ORDER BY 2) AS s;
```

although in practice I have 40+ fields, so having to list them twice is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (tt).id, (tt).name, (tt).greee, tt
from (
    select (id, txt, id+10)::tttpe as tt
    from test
) s
order by 3 desc
```

Without the subselect

```
select
    ((id, txt, id+10)::tttpe).id,
    ((id, txt, id+10)::tttpe).name,
    ((id, txt, id+10)::tttpe).greee,
    (id, txt, id+10)::tttpe as tt
from test
order by 3 desc
```

---

Edit due to very important context change in the commentaries

The ordering done inside a function or a subselect is not guaranteed to be the one of its output, so do not order inside them. But the good news is that it is much easier to access each member of the type from a function

```
create or replace function get_tt()
returns tttpe as $$
    select (id, txt, id+10)::tttpe as tt
    from test;
$$ language sql;

select id, name, greee
from get_tt()
order by 3 desc;
```

But if you want the original object as in the below query then you are back to square one

```
select get_tt();
```

Comment: nice! Anyway to use the index as in `SELECT id, txt, (id+10) as gree FROM test ORDER BY 2`?

Comment: Close, but what I wanted was the output to be the objects ordered by a property, not all the properties broken out. I got something close based on your help and will update it in the answer. If theres a better way let me know. thanks for your help!

Comment: @FrankConry Just add the object to the select list. Updated.

Comment: The context is that this is taking place inside a function that uses `RETURN EXECUTE QUERY` at the end, so extra fields in the outer select are forbidden. I think I'm on the right track with the edit though, right?